# Perform action before onclick action of dynamically loaded button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I currently have a div, in which at a certain time a button is dynamically loaded:
Initially it looks like this:

```
<div id="id"></div>
```

while at some point it becomes

```
<div id="id">
    <button type="button" onclick="function1();"></button>
</div>
```

Now, I want to perform an action onclick *before* `function1` is called. In order to bind an onclick action to a dynamically loaded button I would normally do something along the lines of

```
$("#id").on('click', 'button', function() {
    function2();
});
```

However, I suspect that since the button is loaded dynamically this click handler is overridden by the onclick defined on the button, and only `function1` is called. How can I make sure that on this dynamically loaded button, `function2` is also executed onclick? Please assume I cannot change the onclick attribute that is dynamically loaded.

Comment: can you explain how button is adding dynamically

Comment: I'm working with a checkout system which works in several steps, where the "continue" button in one step loads the next step (including the next "continue" button). My functionality needs to work on one of the "continue" buttons which does not yet exist on page load. I do not want to directly edit this process, but be able to 'drop in' my extra functionality by including a single js file with no editing of the core required.

Answer (score 4):

> Now, I want to perform an action onclick before function1 is called.

Rather than click, use the `mousedown` event since it will invoked before `click` event (as click event is invoked after mouseup)

```
$("#id").on('mousedown', 'button', function() {
    function2();
});
```

or also try (based on discussion in comments below)

```
$("#id").on('mouseup', 'button', function() {
    function2();
});
```

Comment: If I, as user, mousedown on the button, then move my mouse off it and let go, then won't only the mousedown be executed but not the click? Ideally I really only want function2 to be executed if the click is actually performed.

Comment: Following up on this, a solution which does solve my use case is using the `mouseup` event instead of the `mousedown` event, since this occurs at the time the click is completed and not before the user releases the mouse. This doesn't exactly equal a click, since a user an `mousedown` outside the button and `mouseup` inside of it, but in my use case it works.

Comment: @Radical Interesting, since mouseup on an element will still be considered a `click` by system regardless of where user did `mousedown`

Comment: Really? I did not know that. In that case, my previous comment that it doesn't equal a click is incorrect and using the mouseup event actually does exactly what I want (And still solves the problem I had in my initial question, since the mouseup event is separate from the click so the call to `function1` is not overridden)

Answer (score 0):

Following up on [gurvinder372's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37344814/1123303), I solved the problem by hooking into the mouseup event (instead of mousedown as he suggested)

```
$("#id").on('mouseup', 'button', function() {
    function2();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to do something like this:

```
$("#id").on('click', 'button', function() {
return func2();
});

function func2()
{
alert("function2 is alert")
}
```

this will override the function1